# Visual SVN Vs2013

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2013, visualsvn

I'm using VisualSVN to merge a branch with a trunk.  I want archive the trunk into a branch and merge the branch into the trunk, then remove the old branch from the Repository in Visual SVN.  My question is, if I delete the trunk, then cleanly make my current branch the trunk, after I archive the trunk into a branch, how would that be different from Merging my desired branch Into the Trunk?

Right now I have files in the trunk that I would like to archive, So I would like the trunk to reside in a branch.  Whereas the current branch I desire to be my trunk, has files that I do not want in the current build, So If i were to just merge the two (Branch and Trunk) I would have those undesired projects sitting on the repository, unused, and unclean looking.

Is it better to always Merge?  This is what I suspect.